# AngularJS Firebase get the list of object keys

Tags: angularjs, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

Here is my Firebase database, I want to get the object keys as a list:

```
var mydb = DatabaseRef.ref("projects").orderByKey();
        $scope.mylist= $firebaseArray(mydb);
        var data = $scope.mylist;
```

How can I get the keys of the object of `data` as array list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) in this scenario.

It will return an array of strings that represents the properties of the object (keys).